# Let $A=\{\frac{\lfloor nb\rfloor }{n}\},b>0$ prove that $supA=b$

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

**Let $A=\{\frac{\lfloor nb\rfloor }{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\},b>0$ prove that  $supA=b$**

My attempted :

for $0<b\in \mathbb{N}$ we get $A=\{b\} \rightarrow supA=b$

for $0<b\in \mathbb{Q}$ and I stuck here any hint how to continue

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$nb-1<\lfloor nb\rfloor \le nb$$